# Getting error "csc.exe" exited with code -532462766 for brand new asp.net web api project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

I'm getting error

> "csc.exe" exited with code -532462766

for fresh new asp.net **web api** project.

I've deleted the project and solution, removed all files, and tried creating the project from scratch and the same error keeps happening.

This is when I use VS 2015. If I use VS 2017 I get the following instead:

> Could not load type 'Server.WebApiApplication

This is very strange, all my other apps run perfectly fine

Comment: That's an obvious no repro, since thousands of developers are able to generate Web API projects using both editions for years. What did you try and what happened?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is a very strange error. The cause turns out to be that I **can't call my asp.net web api project "server"**.

Note that If I *change the name after I've created* the project doesn't solve the problem. I need to fully delete the project and create a new one with something different than "server".

It seems Visual Studio (both 2015 and 2017) doesn't like to have a project called "server".

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't care. `csc` is the *compiler*. If you mix up namespaces or use the same names as a runtime namespace you'll end up with compilation errors. Would *another programmer* be able to tell whether your code calls a runtime or a local class? You can specify full names if you have to. It's far better to use *unambiguous* names though. Again, imagine whether a coworker would be able to understand what's going on by looking at the code